# LINQ to SQL into LINQ to Objects - switch via AsEnumerable or via ToList

Tags: c#, linq

While there is a necessity of switching from one LINQ driver to another (e.g. because some wanted expressions can be unsupported in the first one) what kind of switch should be used - the `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` ?

```
var r = ent.Users.Select(user => new
        {
            user.Name,
            Organs = user.Attributes.Select(x => x.Organ)
        })
        .AsEnumerable() // switch to LINQ to Objects
        .Select(user => new
        {
            user.Name,
            Organs = string.Join(", ", user.Organs)
        });
```

I understand that `AsEnumerable` is deferred, so it doesn't enumerate the source immediately, but is there any significant difference from usage of `ToList` as the switch here, in practice, instead ?

For LINQ to Objects to run here, the data from SQL should be already available - so it is what `ToList()` will do if used in the place of the switch. Isn't the usage of `AsEnumerable` force something like `ToList` to be invoked internally anyway while evaluation of the expression tree ?

Comment: You should see this: [whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ToList()` will build a new `List<T>` in memory and store all of the objects in it.
That is needless work; you should call `.AsEnumerable()`.

In general, you should only call `.ToList()` when you need to iterate multiple times (and only at the end of a query chain).

Answer (score 0):

While @SLaks already answered your question, for the sake of clarity, I'll quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) on what `.AsEnumerable()` does:

> The AsEnumerable(IEnumerable) method has no effect
>   other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that
>   implements IEnumerable to IEnumerable itself.

It is not related to `ToList()`.