# Caching a result from EF

Tags: entity-framework, caching

I have this method for retrieving a result from my context and caching it using `MemoryCache`.

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerRole> GetCustomerRoles()
{
    string key = String.Format(CC_CACHE_CUSTOMER_ROLE_ALL, "all");
    return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
        {
            return from r in _customerRoleRepository.Table select r;
        }
    );
}
```

I then use this in my view like

```
@foreach (CustomerRole role in Model)
{

}
```

The problem I have is that because the actual result isn't executed until the data is accessed (in my view), it's not actually caching the result.

How do I force this query to run via my caching function rather than waiting until the data is used?

I've not included what `_cacheManager.Get()` does as I know it's caching whatever I send to it properly but if you think that is the problem, let me know and I will post the relative code.

Note: I have tried doing it this way hoping it would force the query to run but still no luck

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerRole> GetCustomerRoles()
{
    string key = String.Format(CC_CACHE_CUSTOMER_ROLE_ALL, "all");
    return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
        {
            var roles = from r in _customerRoleRepository.Table select r;
            return roles.Take(roles.Count());
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a method like ToList() to force linq to get the data. Then just add that list to your cache.

Comment: p.s How come `.AsEnumerable()` didn't do the same? I thought it should (as that is something I tried).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable