# Database.SqlQuery with ViewModel and Include results in blank FK values

Tags: linq, include, viewmodel

I am trying to display a grid of Orders from the Northwind sample database, which has FK references to the Customers and Employees tables. I want to use raw SQL (variable "query") and project to a ViewModel "Order_VM". The ViewModel includes the references to the Customers and Employees entities.

I have tried the following statement, which works fine, but only with the original model "Order" and the DbSet version of SqlQuery:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = db.Orders.SqlQuery(query).AsQueryable().Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Employee);
```

However, I want it to work with the ViewModel "Order_VM" instead (code below) using the Database version of SqlQuery (I assume this is the only way), but the CompanyName (from Customers table) and LastName (from Employees table) display blank in the View (grid).

```
IQueryable<Order_VM> orders = db.Database.SqlQuery<Order_VM>(query).AsQueryable().Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Employee);
```

I have tried with/without the "virtual" keyword for the Customer and Employee entity references in the ViewModel to see if eager vs lazy loading was a factor. However still get blanks. Thanks for any help as I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the following statement, which works fine

No, it doesn't, because the `Include` doesn't do anything. It compiles and runs, but the returned type, `DbSqlQuery<Order>` doesn't have an implementation of `Include`, so the method is ignored. You tried to fix that with the `AsQueryable` call, but that only "re-activates" the extension method `Include`, but it [doesn't magically inject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996264/861716) an `Include` implementation.

`DbSqlQuery` (and `DbRawSqlQuery`, the return type of db.Database.SqlQuery) don't implement `IQueryable<T>`, so original EF query provider is out of scope and won't return.

To execute the `Include` statement it should be possible to modify the executed SQL statement and put some `JOIN`s in there. But EF can only do that when `Include` is called on an object that contains an expression tree, so it can add expressions to this tree. A raw SQL query will never be parsed into an expression tree, but simply be executed as is.

So, these raw SQL queries are only capable of populating flat objects from the column list in the `SELECT` statement. Nested objects (references of collections) will never be materialized. If your view model has a `CompanyName` property, you should have a select statement like `SELECT ..., Company.CompanyName, ...`, so the raw SQL should contain the `JOIN`.

Comment: well, it DOES work, somehow, because the grid does display the CompanyName and the LastName and I do not have them in the ViewModel or the raw SQL. I appreciate your explanation, but there must be some other answer.

Comment: The objects you obtain by the query are still capable of lazy loading. So if you monitor the SQL statements being sent to the database you'll see many queries that fetch individual objects. But that's very inefficient, of course.

Comment: So, what I am attempting to do appears to not be very practical or efficient, hmm, bummer. The ultimate goal behind the raw SQL experiment was to create a dynamic query mechanism. I am aware of the old DynamicLinq project from 2008 as mentioned by Scott Guthrie, but was not comfortable with that. Perhaps there is a better way for me to discover. Thx.

Comment: You can take a look at Entity SQL. Dynamic LINQ is still widely used though.