# How to serialize into a json from entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, jsonserializer

I'm trying to serialize an (Entity Framework 6) entity into json. I am making sure the entry is in memory before serializing via the AsNoTracking() method however I get an error as it cant receive a value form a different table that is referenced in the entry.

```
Inner Exception: When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects.

Exception: JsonSerializationException:  Error getting value from 'TABLE_X' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies....
```

Code:

```
List<Location> locations = new DbContext().Locations.Where(x => x.Type == 1).Take(5).AsNoTracking().ToList();
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locations, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

All I want to do is return a string of the serialized entity. Im not worried about other objects, solely the locations entity.

When I tried disposing of the connection and then json serializing I received the error: `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

I only want to serialize my list, I do not want to return/serialize any foreign dependencies.

Comment: Why do you need to serialize that entity?

Comment: Because I want to store it away in a json file for later. E.g. Unit testing with valid/valuable data.

Comment: I would understand storing POCO classes but now EF entities, but then again you might have different requirements.

Comment: If you specify navigation properties as `Virtual` you should just be able to serialize the full entity straight out of the Db. No need to turn proxies off or create other models. Alternatively you could eager load all navigation properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This an `EF`'s dynamic proxy issue you have to disable it to have your code working

in your class  that inherit from `DbContext`

```
public class MyModelEntities : DbContext
{
   public MyModelEntities()
   {
      //just disable it like this  
      Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Mainly what's happening is that your `JsonConvert` is trying to serialize an object like this `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Location_5E43C6C196972BF0754973E48C9C941092D86818CD94005E9A759B70BF6E48E6`

due to the proxy, which cannot be found  because it's dynamically  created

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `AsNoTracking` method to load to memory the entities you need. The [`ToList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable) method is going to do that job.

Now about your issue, is because the JSON serializer is trying to access to each property on an `Location` instance and you can end up querying for your entire database just because lazy loading is enabled. So, you have two options:

1. [Disable Lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOff) (As @BRAHIMKamel recommended)
2. Use [`JsonIgnore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm) atribute over the navigation properties you don't want to be loaded.

Personally, I prefer the first one, and when I need to load a entity with some specific related entity, I use [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) to load it as part of the query:

```
context.Locations
       .Include(l=>l.State)//eager loading an hypothetical related entity 
       .Where(x => x.Type == 1)
       .Take(5)
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object graph is not too complicated, different approach could be to create simple POCO class, where your `Location` will be mapped from. Let's say `LocationModel`. This could be mapped by hand or for example with AutoMapper.