# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[]'

Tags: c#, linq, list, iqueryable

I have got the following code in my unit test. But, it returns the error mentioned when run.

```
var leaveTypesList = new List<LeaveType>() { leaveType1, leaveType2, leaveType3 };
var leaveTypesQueryable = leaveTypesList.AsQueryable();
mockLeaveTypeRepository.Setup(r => r.GetLeaveTypes()).Returns(leaveTypesQueryable);
var leaveTypeDtos = service.GetLeaveTypes();
```

The error is generated from the last line when the results are returned from the service.

The service code for the `GetLeaveTypes` method listed below, which is a simple accessing of the repository.

```
    public IQueryable<LeaveTypeDto> GetLeaveTypes()
    {
        //return Mapper.Map<IQueryable<LeaveTypeDto>>(leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes());
        return leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes().ProjectTo<LeaveTypeDto>();
    }
```

The repository code is also a simple return of an `IQueryable` of leave types.

```
    public IQueryable<LeaveType> GetLeaveTypes()
    {
        return dbContext.LeaveType.Where(lt => lt.IsActive);
    }
```

Just cannot figure out what is wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the that `leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes()` is actually returning `IQueryable<LeaveType>`?

Comment: What's the return type of `leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes()`?

Comment: Replace the var keyword with the types as they are unclear to the reader

Comment: Reopened. There's more to say about this than simply "use AsQueryable()". For example, *where* use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to map `leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes()` to an `IQueryable` of the matching DTO object. I assume you want this because `leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes()` is an `IQueryable` too and you want to stay in touch with its query provider.

AutoMapper has a [different method](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) for this:

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

...

return leaveTypeRepository.GetLeaveTypes()
           .ProjectTo<LeaveTypeDto>();
```

This returns an `IQueryable<LeaveTypeDto>`, to which you can apply subsequent LINQ methods, that will still be translated into SQL.

And now the reason of the exception. It's because there isn't a default implementation for `IQueryable<T>`. AutoMapper creates `List<LeaveTypeDto>`, but that can't natively be converted into `IQueryable<LeaveTypeDto>`. You can however do things like ...

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LeaveTypeDto>>(source)
Mapper.Map<IList<LeaveTypeDto>>(source)
Mapper.Map<LeaveTypeDto[]>(source)
```

... because for those target types AutoMapper knows which default implementation it should use (`List<T>` or `T[]`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. But the problem still persists. I think the problem is with line three of the first code set where I set the `mockLeaveTypeRepository` to return an `IQueryable` but still it returns an IList. I have added both the service method and also the repository methods for your reference and they both return `IQueryable`s.

Comment: Should be OK. It is set up to return `leaveTypesList.AsQueryable()`, which is a genuine `IQueryable`. `AsQueryable()` actually [*converts* the list to an `IQueryable` implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17996264/861716). From what I can see, I don't understand why you still get the error.

Comment: My bad, I have done something wrong. But now it is working after the usage of QuerableExtensions and ProjectTo rather than a direct map. Thanks for the help.