# Get result function in LINQ without translate to store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I need to get result from a function that it need to run in LINQ query. This result bind to grid but in run time I encounter with this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetName(System.Type, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

This is my Code:

```
public IQueryable GetForRah_CapacityList(XQueryParam param)
{
    var result = (from x in Data()
                  select new
                  {
                      Rah_CapacityId = x.Rah_CapacityId,
                      Rah_CapacityName = x.Rah_CapacityName,
                      Rah_St = Enum.GetName(typeof(Domain.Enums.CapacityState), x.Rah_St),
                      Rah_LinesId = x.Rah_LinesId
                  }).OrderByDescending(o => new { o.Rah_CapacityId });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this method in Linq-To-Entities because LINQ does not know how to translate `Enum.GetName` to sql. So execute it in memory with Linq-To-Objects by using `AsEnumerable` and after the query use `AsQueryable` to get the desired `AsQueryable`:

So either:

```
var result = Data()
             .OrderBy(x=> x.CapacityId)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(x => new
             {
                  Rah_CapacityId = x.Rah_CapacityId,
                  Rah_CapacityName = x.Rah_CapacityName,
                  Rah_St = Enum.GetName(typeof(Domain.Enums.CapacityState), x.Rah_St),
                  Rah_LinesId = x.Rah_LinesId
             })
             .AsQueryable();
```

You should first use `OrderBy` before you use `AsEnumerable` to benefit from database sorting performance. The same applies to `Where`, always do this before `AsEnumerable`(or `ToList`).

Comment: I couldn't compile

Comment: I couldn't use AsEnumerable. I want IQueryable result.

Answer (score 7):

`GetName` couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. You can modify the code as below:

```
 var result = (from x in Data().AsEnumerable()
              select new
              {
                  Rah_CapacityId = x.Rah_CapacityId,
                  Rah_CapacityName = x.Rah_CapacityName,
                  Rah_St = Enum.GetName(typeof(Domain.Enums.CapacityState), x.Rah_St),
                  Rah_LinesId = x.Rah_LinesId
              }).OrderByDescending(o => new { o.Rah_CapacityId });
```

With `.ToList()` after data is loaded, any further operation (such as select) is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory.

**EDIT**: Also your method's return type is `IQueryable` while your query is `IOrderedEnumerable` of *anonymous type*, so you should either change the method's type to `System.Object` or as a better solution create a class, send the values into the class's properties, and then return it.

Comment: Instead of `ToList`(which creates a new List for no reason) you can use `AsEnumerable`

Comment: Instead of ToList I must use AsQueryable() but unfortunately still I receive that error.

Comment: Result of my method is IQueryable

Comment: @S.Akbari you haven't changed the query, you wanted surely "Rah_St = x.Rah_St" , but you have now exact the same as in original query in question

Comment: @SasanKarimi [What's the difference(s) between .ToList(), .AsEnumerable(), AsQueryable()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable)

Comment: 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<<anonymous type: int Rah_CapacityId, string Rah_CapacityName, string Rah_St, int? Rah_LinesId>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @SasanKarimi Clearly your method's return type is `IQueryable` while your query is `IOrderedEnumerable` of `anonymous type`. So you should consider this also.

Comment: when I use your code I couldn't compile. I recieve up error.

Comment: @SasanKarimi Since you want to return Anonymous Type from your method you should either change the method's type to `System.Object` or create a class, shove the values into the property, and then return it.

Comment: I need to IQueryable result

Comment: `return result.AsQueryable();`

Comment: I did that. But recieve "At least one object must implement IComparable." error.