# How to convert from decimal to double in Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Suppose we have table T which has two columns A and B with float and money types respectively. I want to write a linq query like following T-SQL statement:

```
Select A, B, A * B as C 
From SomeTable
Where C < 1000
```

I tried to cast like following

```
var list = (from row in model.Table 
            where ((decimal)row.A) * row.B < 1000 
            select new { A = row.A,
                         B = row.B ,
                         C = ((decimal)row.A) * row.B}
           ).ToList();
```

but it does not allow the cast operation. It throw an exception:

> Casting to Decimal is not supported in Linq to Entity queries, because
>   the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred.

My question is how to convert double to decimal in Linq? I don't want to fetch data from database.
**Update:**
I notice the converting decimal to double works but reverse operation throws the exception. So,
Why can't we convert double to decimal? Does Sql server do the same mechanism in t-sql too? Doesn't it affect precision?

Comment: `It does not allow cast operation` <= what is the Exception and its details? Or is it a compile time error?

Comment: Is the error similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802366/get-result-function-in-linq-without-translate-to-store-expression/41802414#41802414

Comment: Casting to Decimal is not supported in Linq to Entity queries, because the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred.

Comment: Does it work if you cast the decimal to a double for the calculation?

Comment: It does not throw exception in inverse casting.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to fetch data from database" ?

Comment: @Magnus I don't want to retrieve all data of the table. some guy suggested to use IEnumerable solution in other posts. so I dont want memory linq solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a float (double) and a decimal, is that a float is decimal precise. If you give the float a value of 10.123, then internally it could have a value 10.1229999999999, which is very near to 10.123, but not exactly.

A decimal with a precision of x decimals will always be accurate until the x-th decimal.

The designer of your database thought that type A didn't need decimal accuracy (or he was just careless). It is not meaningful to give the result of a calculation more precision than the input parameters.

If you really need to convert your result into a decimal, calculate your formula as float / double, and cast to decimal after AsEnumerable:

(I'm not very familiar with your syntax, so I'll use the extension method syntax)

```
var list = model.Table.Where(row => row.A * row.B < 1000)
    .Select(row => new
    {
        A = row.A,
        B = row.B,
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        A = row.A,
        B = row.B,
        C = (decimal)row.A * (decimal)row.B,
    });
```

Meaning:

- From my Table, take only rows that have values such that row.A * row.B
  < 1000.
- From each selected row, select the values from columns A and B.
- Transfer those two values to local memory (= AsEnumerable),
- for every transferred row create a new object with three properties:

  - A and B have the transferred values.
  - C gets the the product of the decimal values of transferred A and B

Comment: "or he was just careless" That is true. Tnx.

Comment: I convert decimal to double for sake of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid AsEnumerable() explaining to Entity how many fractional digits you want.

```
var list = (from row in model.Table 
            where ((decimal)row.A) * row.B < 1000 
            select new { A = row.A,
                         B = row.B ,
                         C = (((decimal)((int)row.A)*100))/100) * row.B}
           ).ToList();
```