# Convert string to double in linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Convert string to double using LINQ query and get data

```
data1 => string type
data2 => double type
```

Query :

```
var query = get to db
query= query.Where(W => double.Parse(W.data1) >= W.data2).ToList();
```

Error :

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double
>   ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802366/get-result-function-in-linq-without-translate-to-store-expression/41802414#41802414

Comment: Although your query is not about converting string to double!

Comment: The error is because LINQ is trying to transform double.Parse into a SQL expression (which doesn't exit's). see @S.Akbari link to see more details, on how you can filter in memory.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at why you have a numerical value saved as a string in your DB.  If possible I'd suggest fixing that.

Comment: As others have said, fix the schema. This isn't only about convenience, or avoiding a cast. Forcing such a conversion means that *no* indexes that cover `data1` can be used, forcing a full table scan.