# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities in linq join with tuples

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, tuples

I am trying to join two table and create a tuples list but getting error as
'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities'

```
var list = (
    from a in db.CategoryRatings
    join c in db.OverallPerformanceByCategories
        on a.CategoryRatingId equals c.CategoryRatingId
    where c.ReviewId == review.ReviewId
    select(new Tuple<string, double, double>(a.CategoryRatingName, a.CategoryWeight, c.Score))
).ToList(); 

ViewData["ListOverallRating"] = list;
```

I don't want to create an anonymous type list to using tuples, can suggest other way as well.

Comment: I think it couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. I guess using `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802414/2946329

Comment: Fundamentally your problem is that you are asking **SQL server** to create a Tuple, it can't create *Tuples*.  So that's why you should create anonymous objects and after they are returned locally to C# you can then translate/materialize them into whatever object you want (as suggested by Miguel).

Comment: Also, assuming you're using [tag:asp.net-mvc] by your codes references to `ViewData`, I suggest you look into using ViewModels instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the anonymous type to fetch from the database and convert to a Tuple in memory.

```
var list = (
    from a in db.CategoryRatings
    join c in db.OverallPerformanceByCategories
        on a.CategoryRatingId equals c.CategoryRatingId
    where c.ReviewId == review.ReviewId
    select(new {a.CategoryRatingName, a.CategoryWeight, c.Score})
)
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(t =>
    new Tuple<string, double, double>(t.CategoryRatingName, t.CategoryWeight, t.Score))
.ToList(); 

ViewData["ListOverallRating"] = list;
```

Hope this help!