# Does first iteration over .AsEnumerable execute the entire query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

If i've got a linq to sql var (eg: var x = from y in db.Orders ....)
and than i call .AsEnumerable() over that, if i iterate over this elements,
Does the first iteration execute the ENTIRE query? or are parts of them generated in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

`AsEnumerable` will deffer the execution of the query, if you use it in a foreach loop, the query will be executed, the result loaded into memory then you will loop through it.

Check the answer from `@Gert Arnold` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable), it might be useful.

Comment: so this is executed entirely before the first iteration?
foreach (x in linqtosql) <-- here is executed?

Comment: Basically yes, see this MSDN post about query execution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx