# C# byte array contains string inside linq where

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-extensions

I need to check if my byte array contains string in LinQ `Where()` method.
At the moment I have something like:

```
public static bool ContainsSequence(byte[] toSearch, byte[] toFind)
{
    for (var i = 0; i + toFind.Length < toSearch.Length; i++)
    {
        var allSame = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < toFind.Length; j++)
        {
            if (toSearch[i + j] != toFind[j])
            {
                allSame = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allSame)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
var data = MyCollection.Where(x => ContainsSequence(x.ByteArrayValue, myStringToByteArray);
```

but I'm getting exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ContainsSequence

I've read somewhere that I can rewrite `ContainsSequence` method to `Linq.Extensions.Extension` but I have no idea how.
Can someone direct me to a solution?

Comment: Why not just fetch the entire collection by doing `MyCollection.AsEnumerable()` and then doing `.Where()` on that? Unless your collection is extremely large then doing it in memory shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Did you mean:
var data = MyCollection.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ContainsSequence(x.ByteArrayValue, myStringToByteArray);  //?
I'm getting null reference exception when I do this

Comment: This should work: `var data = MyCollection.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ContainsSequence(x.ByteArrayValue, myStringToByteArray);`

Comment: what type is `MyCollection`?

Comment: It's DataSet from my Entity Framework Database. Collection is set of data which I want to load to memory. I didn't realise that is important.

Comment: suggest simplify your `ContainsSequence` by using Linq's `Skip` and `Take` and then `SequenceEqual`

Comment: Can you show us some sample data for `ByteArrayValue` and `myStringToByteArray`?

Comment: If your two sequences are the same then you will return false. Is this by design as it could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

EntityFramework only allows you to use a limited selection of LINQ methods, because, unless you explicitly tell it otherwise, EF doesn't execute them in memory, but converts them into a query and has the SQL provider do it instead. If you want to use your own custom method you will have to do the following:

```
var data = MyCollection.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ContainsSequence(x.ByteArrayValue, myStringToByteArray);
```

What we are doing here is we are casting the collection (which should be a `DbSet` or `IQueryable`) into an `IEnumerable`, on which we can use the custom method.

Be advised however, this has the side effect of loading the entire set into memory. This shouldn't be a problem unless you're dealing with very large amounts of data, but it is something to keep in mind.

You can read more about `AsEnumerable()` and exactly what it does and when to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996264/7662085).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach (var item in MyCollection.ToArray())
{
   var data = item.Where(x => x.ContainsSequence(x.ByteArrayValue, myStringToByteArray));
}
```