# Get Data Based on Filter(Not Mandatory Fields) Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I need to get the data from an entity named `Student` which has the fields (Id, Name, Age, Dob). And I have a request object `StudentFilter`

```
public class StudentFilter 
{
      public int? Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public int Age {get;set;}
      public DateTime Dob {get;set;}
}
```

Now based on that I need to form a query with those filters and get data from the database:

```
public List<Student> Get(StudentFilter  request)
{
     if(request.Id.HasValue && request.Id > 0)
     {
     }

     if(request.Age.HasValue && request.Age > 0)
     {
     }

     if(request.Dob.HasValue)
     {
     }

     _context.<Student>.Get()
}
```

Could someone please do help me here? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific problem you are encountering?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

try this, chain the `.Where` depending on your conditions

```
var query = context.Students.AsQueryable();

if(request.Id.HasValue && request.Id > 0)
{
    //equal query
    query = query.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id.Value);
    /* greater than or less than and equal to query
    *query = query.Where(x => x.Id >= request.Id.Value) or query.Where(x => x.Id <= request.Id.Value) or query.Where(x => x.Id != request.Id.Value)
    */
}

if(request.Age.HasValue && request.Age > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Id == request.Age.Value);
    //same applies to top depending on your condition, can be !=, <=, >= or between (< && >)
}

if(request.Dob.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Id == request.Dob.Value);
    //same applies to top depending on your condition, can be !=, <=, >=
}

//the ONLY part which the query will be executed
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: This is not what I was expecting ... here you are fetching the data and running through different conditions .. which leads to performance issue . I need to form a conditional query based on its input and pass it to the context to get data

Comment: @user12073927 it is not yet running, not yet fetch, as I put the query as `AsQueryable`, it will only execute upon executing `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault` with the `.Where` condition built

Comment: @user12073927 try using `SQL profiler` to see that it is not executed until `query.ToList()` is called with the conditions

Comment: @user12073927 explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827707/2122217

Comment: Will it add multiple condition ? I have tried with predicate filter and it is working now .. thank you 

Comment: @user12073927 yes it will, hope you could mark it as answer if it was helpful